# vlc installation in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: installation, vlc, ubuntu-16.10

My vlc was working file but after installing octave vlc crashed.
I tried to reinstall it and repair it with below codes but it did't work

```
$ sudo apt-get purge vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
Package 'vlc' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

$sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that
some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) but it is not going to be installed or
            libgles1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried installing libgles1-mesa

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgles1-mesa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgles1-mesa : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 13.0.4-1ubuntu1~16.10~0.1) but 
17.0.3~git20170404+17.0.71d2f05a-0ubuntu0ricotz2~yakkety is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then I tried libglapi-mesa

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version (17.0.3~git20170404+17.0.71d2f05a-   0ubuntu0ricotz2~yakkety).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

How am I supposed to solved it.

Comment: This question has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/940320/58950) for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The `vlc-nox` package installs `vlc`

To remove, use:

`sudo apt-get purge vlc-nox`

Next, to reinstall vlc, use:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

Answer (score 0):

I only get it to work using master branch of VLC

https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily

first add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% sudo snap install vlc
```

VLC for Debian and many other Linux distributions is also packaged using snap packages. This allows us to distribute latest and greatest VLC versions directly to end users, with security and critical bug fixes, full codec and optical media support.
To install via snap: